# Getting error: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified

Tags: oracle, api, wso2, http-post, nls-lang

Wrote a simple query for post api which is as follows:

`SELECT * FROM TEST2 t WHERE t.correlation_id = 1;`

However, getting the error that can not access nls datafiles or environment specified. Unable to understand how to resolve this. I am working at the windows machine.
Any help or guidance would mean a lot. Thank You!

I tried to query data through post api using oracle database. but getting an error.

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: It sounds like your don't have `ORACLE_HOME` set? Make sure the environment is configured as Oracle expects.